# How can I refresh my screen or run initial process in background

Tags: android

My main screen has a process which can take 20-30 seconds to load the information on to the screen. While this is happening the screen is just black. I have tried using a ProgressDialog to let the user know the process is running but as the screen is black you cannot see it. Can I refresh the screen so that the dialog is visible or do I need to run my initial process in background so that the screen is visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that takes over ~200ms should be run as a background task.  You can either use an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`/`Handler` combination.

- [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [Painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)
- [Threading](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading)
- [Designing for responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)
- [Thread documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)
- [Handler documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)